# erratic cursor movement after Ubuntu upgrade and update

Tags: mouse

Toshiba laptop, upgraded to newest Ubuntu version, then pointer started to stick in place, then mover jerkily then disappear then 2 pointers appeared. Have to reboot several times a session to get pointer to work right. I refer to the touchpad pointer not any other pointer

Comment: You've provided no specifics?  Please be specific; what do you mean by latest version?  The latest Ubuntu Core is Ubuntu Core 22, the latest Desktop release is Ubuntu 23.04, the latest Server is Ubuntu Server 23.04 but you've not said which, nor what changes were made, what update? (package update? if so what packages?) and were any changes made during the last session before this occurred?  (*changes made in the last session before the current behavior was noticed are critical*).